# Python 2.8: principled BSDF get linked base color

Tags: materials, color

I an trying to capture all possible values of the base color slot of the Principled BSDF. I have found ways to get the default color or a linked texture slot of the Principled BSDF, but having trouble getting to get a linked color (for example when a RGB color node is hooked up as a link to the base color value).

context: I'm trying to optimize an exporter. Right now it has support for linked texture maps and default colors, but hooking up color nodes to the base color value is not supported.

Comment: Use [`InputSocket.is_linked`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html?highlight=is_linked#bpy.types.NodeSocket.is_linked) and [`NodeLink.from_node`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.NodeLink.html?highlight=from_node#bpy.types.NodeLink.from_node) attributes... If you don't use them how do you get/support *linked* texture maps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand it correctly, using nodelink.from_node mean that I have to evaluate every possible condition of incoming node (rgb node, mix, color correction nodes ...).

I was wondering whether there's a more efficient way than check for every possible node that could be link to base color?

Comment: `NL.from_node` returns a reference of the connected node and I don't think there is another way to get the color...

Comment: Usually it's the first output of the node which gets connected to the color input of the bdsf, so you could do NodeLink.from_node().outputs[0].default_value to get the input color, since it will work wether the linked node is a RGB, color correction, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Two more follow up questions: (1) how would you evaluate the datatype of NodeLink.from_node().outputs[0].default_value  (I'd need to know whether it's a simple color value or a map (for example a color correction node could be passing a single color or a color corrected map)   (2) If the data type is a map, does the python API provide a way to write a texture t the drive? In other words: how would you go about writing a color corrected map to the drive?

Comment: Or another way to put it: is there a way to detect whether there's a map linked to the base color slot (the map might be passed through a node like a color correction) and if so, is there a way to bake that incoming map?

Comment: Please edit your question instead @Schiette Also please add your current code to the question. And consider to ask only one question per post, read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask